# Asterisk (*) vs. colon (:) in R formulas

Tags: r, statistics, interaction

I always thought that `*` and `:` meant the same thing when adding interaction terms in R formulas. For example:

- `amount_of_gas ~ temperature*gas_type`
- `amount_of_gas ~ temperature:gas_type`

However, now that I've started using Generalized Linear Models (`glm()` in R) I see that these generate different scores, different estimates, etc. when I switch between the two. Can someone explain to me why this happens? Is it a problem with the `stats` package in R?

##UPDATE##
April 26th, 2021

It's been ~4.5 years or so since I asked this question and I keep getting notified that it still has a lot of traffic.
Here's the short answer: y~x*z basically means: y~x+z+x:z while y~x:z is just the interaction of x and z (as described in the answer below)

Comment: [This](http://conjugateprior.org/2013/01/formulae-in-r-anova/) explains it pretty well, which I found by Googling "asterisk vs colon in R modelling"

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Now that you've started using GLMs, wouldn't it be natural to read `?glm`? It's all there.

Comment: hmmmm i might try that. You're input has been so valuable.

Comment: @RichScriven, but now this post is the first hit when googling "asterisk vs colon in R modelling"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From `help(formula)`:

```
 In addition to ‘+’ and ‘:’, a number of other operators are useful
 in model formulae.  The ‘*’ operator denotes factor crossing:
 ‘a*b’ interpreted as ‘a+b+a:b’.
```