# fixed effects interactions lmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to fit a glmm model on my data and I am not sure how to include an interaction between some of my fixed effects.  Im using the `glmer` function from `lme4`.

```
glmer(x ~ a + b + a*b + (1|random))
glmer(x ~ a + b + a:b + (1|random))
glmer(x ~ a*b + (1|random))
```

is writing the `a` and the `b` separately redundant??

Comment: `a*b` expands to `a + b + a:b`, although R doesn't have trouble with the redundant terms if you mistakenly write things as you did in your first model.  See the help page for `formula` (and [this related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567421/vs-in-r-for-modelling)) for more details.