# What are the differences of `:` and `%in%` in R formula notation?

Tags: r, formula, grammar

Here is the description of these two operators from the doc [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models):

```
M_1 : M_2
The tensor product of M_1 and M_2. If both terms are factors, then the “subclasses” factor.

M_1 %in% M_2
Similar to M_1:M_2, but with a different coding.
```

This does not actually tell the difference between the two. My questions are,

1. What's the difference between `M_1 : M_2` and `M_1 %in% M_2` **as formula notations**, or under what circumstances do we have to use the former or the latter?
2. What does `with a different coding` mean in this context?

Comment: `:` means to,`%in%` means `in` and will return a boolean. See for instance `1:4` and `1 %in% 4`. 1 to 4 here would form a numeric vector of 1 to 4 while `%in%` just tests if something is in a given vector

Comment: @NelsonGon that is not true in the formula context, which the part of the docs OP is referencing.

Comment: That's right. It seems the question was edited or I missed it when I commented. Sorry! @Brian.

Comment: Since this was edited, my earlier comment is erroneous. See this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567421/asterisk-vs-colon-in-r-formulas `%in%` here means nesting instead too.